# How to set certain number of listener on one server and no listener on other server for same queue in spring amqp as we can not set 0 concurrency?

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I have setup listeners on reply queues, I want those to be only on master (from where messages are queued) and other servers should have no listeners to reply queue. They should have listeners to all other queues.

Spring AMQP doesn't allow to set listener concurrency to be set to 0. So I cant set 0 listners to reply queue on slave servers.

How do I set 0 concurrency on slave servers for reply queues ?

Comment: Put a flag in DB to know whether there is a listener attached with reply queue already. so, you can have a single listener to be attached with the queue

Comment: I am not trying to check whether listers are attached or not already. I just want 0 concurrency on slave servers which spring amqp doesnt allow. I know it can be done by removing listeners configurations from child servers but the code base would be different then which I want to avoid. Looking for better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it using spring profiles. I just added "master" profile to all listener beans and activated master profile only on master server.

Few nice articles to begin with using profiles

http://diarmuidmoloney.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/spring-environments/

http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/03/27/spring-3-1-profiles-and-tomcat-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Use `auto-startup="false"` and only `start()` the container that you want to listen.

Comment: won't spring profile work like mentioned in other answser? Listeners beans will be registered only on master server where I will make master profile active and on slave I wont make master profile active so listener beans wont be registered on slave. Is it bad approach ?

Comment: and I dont need to start containers manually in that case as there are many containers.

Comment: Yes, I was just offering another alternative that would allow you to warm-start one of the other instances if the current one dies.